# combine multiple rows into a single row with repeating set of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with multiple insurance policies per client. One Policy per record.
I need to represent all the policies in one row per client.

I have read all the similar questions and they may be close but I don't seem to be able to translate the answers into my situation.

The table that I have looks like this

```
enter code here  Client-ID     Ins-Company   Policy-Number   Start-Date
                 1             BCBS          BSBC1           2018-01-01
                 1             Aetna         Aetna1          2017-01-01
                 1             Self-Pay      N/A             2016-01-01
                 2             Self-Pay      N/A             2015-01-01
                 3             BCBS          BCBS3           2014-01-01
                 3             Self-Pay      N/A             2013-01-01
```

Expected Result:

```
enter code here Client-ID Ins-Co1  Policy1  Start1      Ins-Co2   Policy2 Start2     Ins-Co3  Policy3 Start3
                1         BCBS     BCBS1    2018-01-01  Aetna     Aetna1  2017-01-01 Self-Pay  N/A    2016-01-01
                2         Self-Pay N/A      2015-01-01
                3         BCBS     BCBS3    2014-01-01  Self-Pay   N/A    2013-01-01
```

In need to create another table with these records

Comment: This is usually done with some type of "Pivot" function, which depends on your RDMS (mySQL, Oracle, Teradata, etc...). If you tag the question with the database system you are working with you'll get a good answer.

Comment: Related/similar, by the same poster: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55788065/7233423

Comment: Used this code as a Template and it worked great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the result I needed with the following code.

First, I created a View of the source table that added a Row Number using the following Function:
`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.Client_ID ORDER BY a.Billing_Order ASC) AS Row_No`

and built the following Code

```
enter code hereDECLARE @sql varchar(max)
DECLARE @colList varchar(max)

--create dynamic list of columns
SELECT @colList = 
STUFF
(
  (
   SELECT + ',' + 
   quotename(colName + Row_No)
   FROM Credible_Client_Insurance_Raw_Data_Query
   CROSS APPLY
   (
     SELECT 1 As Ord, 'Payer_ID' ColName UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 As Ord, 'Billing_Order' UNION ALL
     SELECT 3 As Ord, 'Insurance_ID' UNION ALL
     SELECT 4 As Ord, 'Group_No' UNION ALL
     SELECT 5 As Ord, 'Copay_Fee' UNION ALL
     SELECT 6 As Ord, 'Start_Date' 
    ) v 
    GROUP BY colName, Ord, Row_No
    ORDER BY Row_No, Ord
   for xml path(''), type
   ).value('/','varchar(max)'),1,1,''
)

--unpivot columns into rows and then apply pivot
SET @sql
= '
SELECT Client_ID, ' + @colList + ' 
FROM
(
   SELECT Client_ID, ColVal,
   colName + Row_No ColName
   FROM Credible_Client_Insurance_Raw_Data_Query
   CROSS APPLY
   (
     SELECT Payer_ID As ColVal, ''Payer_ID'' ColName UNION ALL
     SELECT Billing_Order, ''Billing_Order'' UNION ALL
     SELECT Insurance_ID, ''Insurance_ID'' UNION ALL
     SELECT Group_No, ''Group_No'' UNION ALL
     SELECT CAST(Copay_Fee AS VARCHAR), ''Copay_Fee'' UNION ALL
     SELECT CAST(Start_Date AS VARCHAR), ''Start_Date'' 
   ) v 
) A
PIVOT
(
   MAX(ColVal) FOR ColName IN (' + @colList + ')
) P1 '


EXEC(@sql)
```

Code was copied from another question

Pivot on multiple columns based on single column

---

Now I have a follow up question:

Now that I created a query that provides the result I need

I need to place the result into a table.

I cannot take this query and make it into a VIEW because it starts with a Declare Statement ( Illegal for Views )

So how do I transfer this query data into a Table?

Comment: Used the Code provided with slight modification.

Code worked Well and I have completed my project.

Thanks for ALL Your Help.  

Answer Accepted